# How to check if file is empty in SQL script?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Below are my jobs created for my stored procedure "ListDailyInbound855-InputScript.sql.
**First job (Generate File)** creates the ouput "D:\DailyReports\Inbound855.txt"

```
sqlcmd -i D:\InputSQLScripts\ListDailyInbound855-InputScript.sql  
-S localhost -E -s " " -o D:\DailyReports\Inbound855.txt
```

**Second job (Email File)** creates an email to be sent out to support@company.com.

```
Declare @ExeFilePath varchar(255)
Set  @ExeFilePath = 'D:\Applications\EmailUtility\Mailer '

Declare @cmd varchar(500)
Set @cmd = @ExeFilePath + ' "Host:smtp.emailserver.com"  "To:EDISupport@ 
company.com"   "Cc:support@ company.com" "From:support@ company.com" 
"Disp:EDI Support" "Sub: Daily Inbound 855 Report" "Msg:Please find 
report attached." "Atch:D:\DailyReports\Inbound855.txt"'

Declare @output int
Exec    @output = master..xp_cmdshell @cmd,no_output

If  @output <> 0
Begin
    RaisError('Error while sending email.', 16, 1)
    Return
End
```

**Problem:** I need to check first if the output "D:\DailyReports\Inbound855.txt" is non-empty before using it as attachment to the email
and therefore not receiving it as empty. My goal is only to receive email alerts if attachment has content or non-empty. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: From the use of `master..xp_cmdshell` this is probably a SQL Server question, but it would help if you tagged the question as such (possibly with the right version: run SELECT @@VERSION for that).

Answer (score 3):

Since you already are using an executable, the best approach may be to modify it to include the check for empty; assuming you have the sources of course.

As an alternative you can try queries such as the following to load the file into a recordset:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'<filename>', SINGLE_CLOB ) AS Contents -- for ASCII/ANSI
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'<filename>', SINGLE_NCLOB) AS Contents -- for UNICODE
```

And then check the result using additional statements:

```
DECLARE @LEN INT
SELECT @LEN = Len(Contents.BulkColumn) FROM
    OPENROWSET(BULK N'<filename>', SINGLE_CLOB) AS Contents

IF @LEN > 0
BEGIN
    -- rest of code
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following CMD line to find out the file size (in this example "c:\test.txt"):

```
for %I in ("c:\test.txt") do echo %~zI;
```

We need to get result into the MSSQL variable. So you should use `EXIT` instead of `ECHO` to return result of a command as an exit code. In this case you can assign it to MSSQL variable.

Another issue when the file doesn't exist. In this case you will get an error because `%~zI` is empty. To avoid this just add `0` before `%~zI`. So we get 00,01,02,.. instead of 1,2,.. and when it is output as an EXIT code it will be converted to the int value 0,1,2,3,... If file doesn't exist you get 0.

Here is the test script:

```
DECLARE @output int
EXEC   @output = master..xp_cmdshell 'for %I in ("c:\test.txt") do EXIT 0%~zI;',no_output;
SELECT @output;
```

If `@output = 0` then file doesn't exist or size of the file is 0.

Comment: How would you pass a parameter instead of hard coding file location?  The file name changes daily for me.

Comment: DECLARE    filepath VARCHAR (MAX) = <FIle path>   test VARCHAR (50)  SET @test = 'for %I in ("''' + @filepath+'''") do EXIT 0%~zI;'